# WireMock serve response from file and keep connection alive

Tags: wiremock

We have a peculiar scenario we want to test.

We'll be consuming an HTTP stream which would stay open during certain time-frame. The stream consists of plain-text lines (CSV) and it's streamed using the chunked transfer encoding.

When we connect we expect to get all the data from, possibly, a file on the server side, and once that bulk is being served the connection stays alive, as it's possible that there would be more data transferred over the same connection.

Is it possible for Wiremock to serve everything from a file and keep the connection alive (doesn't send an empty chunk to signal the end of stream)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

While WireMock will keep *connections* alive by default per the HTTP 1.1 spec, it will always terminate the *response* once everything has been sent, either via the empty chunk or by setting `Content-Length`.

What you're trying to do (if I understand correctly) is stream out multiple payloads within the context of a single *response*, which WireMock doesn't have a means for doing.

A possible solution might be for you to concatenate all your response parts into a single file, although I suspect you've discounted that option for reasons not stated.

Another possibility would be to supply your own `FileSource` implementation to WireMock and thus provide your own `InputStreamSource` which would give you more control over how the underlying file(s) are streamed out in the response.

Comment: Thanks Tom, yeah the understanding is correct.

We'll try with a custom FileSource impl, good idea!